# SQL Cross apply statement performing poorly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization

The following statement is executing unexpectedly slowly, the child table does hold a lot of rows but the parent does not, indexing looks good - I think there's a better way to do this.

```
SELECT P.[ID] 
,C1.[MinChildDate]
,C2.[MaxChildDate]
FROM Parent AS P
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT 
MIN([Date]) AS MinChildDate
FROM Child 
WHERE Child.ParentID=P.ID
) AS C1
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT 
MAX([Date]) AS MAXChildDate
FROM Child 
WHERE Child.ParentID=P.ID
) AS C2
```

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple group by query:

```
SELECT
      P.[ID]
    , MIN(child.[Date]) AS MinChildDate
    , MAX(child.[Date]) AS MAXChildDate
FROM Parent AS P
      INNER JOIN Child ON P.ID = Child.ParentID
GROUP BY
      P.[ID]
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove a `CROSS APPLY` to cut the logical reads of the `Child` table in half.

```
SELECT P.[ID] 
,C1.[MinChildDate]
,C1.[MaxChildDate]
FROM Parent AS P
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT 
MIN([Date]) AS MinChildDate,
MAX([Date]) AS MAXChildDate
FROM Child 
WHERE Child.ParentID=P.ID
) AS C1
```